# Почему файл не читается без функции read(), но при этом когда раскладываешь через цикл, то всё работает?

Tags: python, файлы, текстовые-файлы

Почему файл не читается без функции read() в данном примере?

```
with open('pi_digits.txt') as text_file:
print(text_file.read())
```

При этом в этом случае функция не требуется и всё работает.

```
with open('pi_digits.txt') as text_file:
for list_file in text_file:
    print(list_file)
```

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться. Не пойму принципа работы python в данном случае, спасибо.

> Пример файла:
> 3.1415926535
> 8979323846
> 2643383279

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, наверное потому что вы забыли что такое отступы и зачем они используются в Python

```
with open('my_first_file.txt') as text_file:
    print(text_file.read())
```

Все работает. Результат:

```
Наша Таня громко плачет,
уронила в речку мячик,
тише, Танечка, не плачь,
не утонет в речке мяч
```

Во-вторых, а как без функции `read` - или функций/методов ее заменяющих - вы собрались читать?  На всякий случай - `text_file` -  это не ваш файл, а специальный объект, который дает вам возможность работы с файлом. Вот вы и используете такие методы -  в первом случае `read()`, во втором - это делает за вас интерпретатор, который умеет правильно интерпретировать работу с итерируемым объектом в конструкции `in text_file`